# How to render colours properly in Java Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I was using this code placed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849151/bar-chart-in-java) to generate bar-charts for my datasets. However, the colours were all the same (red in the code), so I decided to generate a colour ramp for this. I wrote the following code:

```
Color[] getColorRamp(int numColours)
{
    Color[] colours = new Color[numColours];
    int red_1 = 255; 
    int green_1 = 0; 
    int blue_1 = 0; 
    int red_2 = 0; 
    int green_2 = 0; 
    int blue_2 = 255; 

    int count = 0; 

    for (float t=0.0f;t<1.0f;t+=1.0/(float)numColours) {
        colours[count] = new Color((int)(t*red_2 + (1-t)*red_1),
                (int)(t*green_2 + (1-t)*green_1),
                (int)(t*blue_2 + (1-t)*blue_1),34); 

        //System.out.print((int)(t*red_2 + (1-t)*red_1) +",");
        //System.out.print((int)(t*green_2 + (1-t)*green_1) +",");
        //System.out.println((int)(t*blue_2 + (1-t)*blue_1));
    }
    return colours; 
}
```

It is here, where the problem starts. Only the first colour (pretty light blue) get rendered properly. Other colours are rendered as black! You can see that I have put `System.out.println` to verify the colours generated (commented in the code posted here). I saw that colours were generated as perfect RGB combinations.

The modified barchart function is posted here:

```
void drawBarChart(Graphics g, double[] values, String[] names, String title)
{ 

    if (values == null || values.length == 0)
        return;
    double minValue = 0;
    double maxValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (minValue > values[i])
            minValue = values[i];
        if (maxValue < values[i])
            maxValue = values[i];
    }

    //Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gg; 

    Dimension d = getSize();
    int clientWidth = d.width;
    int clientHeight = d.height;
    int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;

    Font titleFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
    FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
    Font labelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(labelFont);

    int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
    int y = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
    int x = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
    g.setFont(titleFont);
    g.drawString(title, x, y);

    int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
    int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();
    if (maxValue == minValue)
        return;
    double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
    y = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
    g.setFont(labelFont);

    Color[] colours = getColorRamp(values.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        int valueX = i * barWidth + 1;
        int valueY = top;
        int height = (int) (values[i] * scale);
        if (values[i] >= 0)
            valueY += (int) ((maxValue - values[i]) * scale);
        else {
            valueY += (int) (maxValue * scale);
            height = -height;
        }

        g.setColor(colours[i]);
        g.fillRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
        int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(names[i]);
        x = i * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
        g.drawString(names[i], x, y);
    }       
    //paintComponent(g);
}
```

I wish to know, what mistake I am making!

Comment: This could be a byte under/overflow issues

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to hit yourself on the head now. The reason it fails is that you forget to increase the variable `count` after setting the first colour, so you're constantly overwriting the first element of the Color array, and leaving all the other values in the array as their initial default (`null`).

Fixed code:

```
for (float t=0.0f;t<1.0f;t+=1.0/(float)numColours) {
    colours[count++] = new Color((int)(t*red_2 + (1-t)*red_1),
            (int)(t*green_2 + (1-t)*green_1),
            (int)(t*blue_2 + (1-t)*blue_1),34); 
}
```

(Notice the `colours[count++]`)